# How to get an immutable value of a collection

Tags: c#, algorithm, design-patterns, collections

As part of my presentation architecture I have a base class that implements IEditableObject, So when BeginEdit() takes a snapshot of state, a Dictionary is created via reflection for all writable, non-collection properties.

```
var propertyInfos = GetType().GetWritableNonCollectionPropertyInfos();
var dic = propertyInfos
            .ToDictionary(pi => pi.Name, pi => pi.GetValue(this, null));
```

This dictionary is the basis for IsDirty tracking and rolling back on CancelEdit().

The reason the default behavior excludes collections is because they are usually just not necessary, potentially expensive to enumerate, and just generally a pain.

To the point of this question, I have an use case where the collection state *is* necessary. It's a HashSet of custom objects, and will rarely have more than 5 at a time. As you can see from the code above, the value of the collection will wind up being a reference to the collection itself; which will change as the collection changes, and so you can't tell if it is actually dirty or not.

So I need to store some value for the collection that will be both immutable and comparable to the value of the collection as it changes. Here is the general idea for what I came up with:

1. provide a protected IncludeCollections flag
2. when the flag is true give subclasses a template method to return additional key value pairs of only collection properties

   ```
       if(IncludeCollections) {
           var collectionOnlyDictionary = GetCollectionOnlyDictionary();
           foreach (var kvp in collectionOnlyDictionary) {                 
               dic.Add(GetCollectionKey(kvp.Key), kvp.Value);
           }
       }
   ```
3. Provide another template method to get some immutable value for the collection. This should allow for variations, but in general maybe an algorithm like this

   ```
   protected  override object GetLatestCollectionValue(string key) {
       if (key != _key_AgeHistoryCollection)
           return null;
       return GetImmutableCollectionValue(AgeHistory);
   }  

   protected static object GetImmutableCollectionValue<T>(ICollection<T> c) {
       var hash = c.Count.GetHashCode();
       unchecked {
           hash = c.Aggregate(hash, (current, i) => current += i.GetHashCode());
       }
       return hash;        
   }
   ```

This actually seems to work, but... its complicated! Does anyone see a simpler and/or more efficient way to track collection state?

And the gist of the question, which really is answerable, does the GetImmutableCollectionValue method look like a good general purpose algorithm to get an immutable value for a collection?

Cheers

## A Solution

At the risk of further offending "the question cannot be answered police"... here is a solution.

Yes, I think the general algorithm is useful, and I added it as an extension. I added another extension to speed up and simplify the process for a collection based on a domain superclass that has a DisplayName property:

```
    public static int GetVmCollectionHashCode<T>(this ICollection<T> c) where T : ViewModelBase
    {
        if (c == null)
            return 0;

        var hash = c.Count.GetHashCode();
        unchecked
        {
            hash = c.
                Aggregate(hash, (current, i) => current += i.DisplayName.GetHashCode());
        }
        return hash;
    }
```

BUT the real insight I came to is that instead of cluttering and complicating my EditingNotifier superclass with collection handling, was to encapsulate the collection itself into a class, and notify it's containing class after a modification, so:

```
/// <summary>
/// A collection with the ability to broadcast <see cref="Messenger"/> notifications
/// when the collection is altered. Subscribers that need to know if they are dirty 
/// because this collection was modified can use the information to calculate a stateful
/// proerty using <see cref="EditingHelpers.GetVmCollectionHashCode{T}"/>,
/// </summary>
public class PcmDetailCollectionVm : ObservableCollection<PcmDetailVm>
{
    #region Creation

    public PcmDetailCollectionVm(IEnumerable<PcmDetailVm> pcms) : base(pcms) {

        // set INPC for each vm
        foreach (var vm in this)
            vm.PropertyChanged += OnDetailVmChanged;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Collection Modification Handlers

    public void AddDetailVm(PcmDetailVm item) {
        Add(item);
        item.PropertyChanged += OnDetailVmChanged;
        Messenger.GetInstance.Notify(MessengerMessages.PcmCollectionChanged, this);
    }

    public void RemoveDetailVm(PcmDetailVm item) {
        Remove(item);
        Messenger.GetInstance.Notify(MessengerMessages.PcmCollectionChanged, this);
    }

    private readonly string _propName_DisplayName = ExprHelper.GetPropertyName<ViewModelBase>(vm => vm.DisplayName);

    private void OnDetailVmChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        if (e.PropertyName == _propName_DisplayName)
            Messenger.GetInstance.Notify(MessengerMessages.PcmCollectionChanged, this);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Now the containing class just needs a simple property that is updated on receipt of a notification, and state tracking proceeds as normal.

/// containing class

```
Messenger.GetInstance.Register(MessengerMessages.PcmCollectionChanged, (Action<PcmDetailCollectionVm>)(OnPcmCollectionChanged));


    public int DetailVmsHashCode
    {
        get { return _detailVmsHashCode; } 
        protected set {
            if (_detailVmsHashCode == value)
                return;
            _detailVmsHashCode = value;
            Notify(() => DetailVmsHashCode);
        }
    }
    private int _detailVmsHashCode;

    private void OnPcmCollectionChanged(PcmDetailCollectionVm obj)
    {
        if(!ReferenceEquals(obj, DetailVms))
            return;
        DetailVmsHashCode = DetailVms.GetVmCollectionHashCode();
    }
```

Life is good again...

Comment: There's some good stuff here... I don't know: tl;dr. But the main thing is you need to follow the Q&A format: present the problem as a question. Then, in a separate post that answers the question, post your solution. Be prepared for some critique... you may find someone else posts something you should accept instead of your intended answer. This also helps your tl;dr problem by breaking up the article a bit.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn. The other side of that coin is that the context and solution motivation might not have come across. And I did end the original post with a question. Not saying it couldn't have been presented in a more focused way, but I also believe it has value, as is, to someone who has some familiarity with the design problem. Cheers